# compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I am trying to use forms in angular. I was using official document to make a simple form.

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
    <p>this works?</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

However its gives error. Everything works fine if I don't use `<mat-form-field>`.
my main.component.ts file is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Bau_item } from '../shared/Bau_item';
import {MatFormFieldModule , MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
//import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  // bau_items: Bau_item[]=[
  //    {
  //       id:1,
  //       industry:'industry',
  //       name_of_client: 'name_of_client',
  //       software_tested: 'software_tested',
  //       software_version: 'software_version',
  //       supported_business: 'supported_business',
  //       module_tested: 'module_tested',
  //       business_product_tested: 'business_product_tested'
  //   },
  //   {
  //      id:2,
  //      industry:'industry',
  //      name_of_client: 'name_of_client',
  //      software_tested: 'software_tested',
  //      software_version: 'software_version',
  //      supported_business: 'supported_business',
  //      module_tested: 'module_tested',
  //      business_product_tested: 'business_product_tested'
  //  }
  //
  // ]

  // displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  // dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
  //
  //   applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  //     filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
  //     filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
  //     this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  //   }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

THe error in chrome console is

```
compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">
    [ERROR ->]<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter"): ng:///AppModule/MainComponent.html@2:4
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24668)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:34621)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34596)
    at eval (compiler.js:34497)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34497)
    at eval (compiler.js:34367)
    at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)
```

Comment: you need to add `MatFormFieldModule` to your module's imports array.

Comment: Was about to say this ^. Everything you want to use in the template your need to import in the module. You can basicly see the module as the parent of the template and component.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the error occurred because you forgot to import all necessary modules. In newer Angular Material version, if you want to deal with `mat-form-field`, you have to import both `MatFormFieldModule` and `MatInputModule`. As I see, you just forgot to import `MatInputModule`.

And you have to import this modules into module, not into component, and include them to `imports` array.

Comment: This is my favorite trap. I also tend to forget to add it ... It is very easy to miss

Comment: @DavidVotrubec, yes, I agree)